# How to send information from HTML <input> element to <span> using JavaScript .innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to JavaScript and trying to mimic an example in a book I'm reading.  I would like to take what is input to a HTML  element and send the data to a  element using .innerHTML.  I don't know what is wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>JS Form</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="date">
     <table>
      <tr><td><input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Please input name"    onchange="greeting();"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td><span id="hello"></span></td>
      </tr> 
     </table>
   </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function greeting() {
     var user = document.date.user.value;
     var hello = document.getElementById("hello");
     hello.innerHTML = "How are you " + user;
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `name="date"` to your form tag like below. Else `document.date.user.value` will not work.

```
<form id="date" name="date">
```

Another way to get around the issue, is accessing the `date` property of the `window` object.

```
window.date.user.value;
```

This is possible because you've set an `id` on the form.

Or you might consider accessing the `form` using its `id` and then get user value as follows:

```
var user = document.getElementById("date").user.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

For simplification, and depending on your browser, you could use `document.querySelector`. Take a look at this very helpful SO post:
[JavaScript: how to get value of text input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value)

Comment: It's one of my favorite posts here on SO. Certainly better than any W3 tutorial. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you should do this first:

```
var user= document.getElementsByName("user");
var hello = document.getElementById("hello");
 hello.innerHTML = "How are you " + user[0].value;
```